# GMail API auto authorization for read mail

Tags: c#, gmail-api, google-authentication

I am using gmail api to read mail from mail account. But to access mail i have to authorize by selecting or login the mail. If it's only one mail and it's already logged in, it can auto authorize without have select the mail. But if multiple account logged in i have to select the mail to authorize. My goal is to authorize multiple gmail account without selecting the mail. Because this mail reading function will run in crone job. I use following code for authorization.
Thanks in advance.

```
UserCredential credential;
        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(userfilepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            String FolderPath = Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CredentialsInfo"]);
            String FilePath = Path.Combine(FolderPath, "APITokenCredentials");

            var flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
            {
                ClientSecrets = new ClientSecrets
                {
                    ClientId = cid,
                    ClientSecret = csecret
                },
                Scopes = new[] { GmailService.Scope.MailGoogleCom },
                DataStore = new FileDataStore(FilePath, true)
            });

            var token = new Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponse()
            {
                AccessToken = accesstoken,
                ExpiresInSeconds = 3600,
                Issued = DateTime.Now
            };

            credential = new UserCredential(flow, usermail, token);






            // Create Gmail API service.


            var refreshResult = credential.RefreshTokenAsync(CancellationToken.None).Result;
            GmailService service = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
            });
            return service;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case the best option is using a [Service Account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts), these types of accounts are intended for non-human access.

Examples:

- Running workloads on virtual machines (VMs).
- Running workloads on on-premises workstations or data centers that call Google APIs.
- Running workloads which are not tied to the lifecycle of a human user.

##### Documentation

- [C# Google API Github](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client)
- [.NET Gmail API Documentation](https://googleapis.dev/dotnet/Google.Apis.Admin.Directory.directory_v1/latest/api/Google.Apis.Admin.Directory.directory_v1.html)